# Netlogo: ask turtle to reproduce after it completes a procedure, and ask new turtle to repeat that procedure for itself

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and am attempting to model home range selection of subsequent colonizers. The model should follow simple steps:

1. Individual 1 picks a home range (a subset of patches).
2. When individual 1 is done picking its home range, it hatches new
   individual 2.
3. Individual 2 picks a home range, then hatches individual 3.
4. Individual 3 picks a home range, and so on.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this to work. I can get the first turtle to pick a home range. But the offspring do not. Writing the code numerous ways has only accomplished two unintended outcomes. Either endless new individuals are hatched simultaneously, before the first turtle has a home range, and the new turtles fail to pick a home range. Or, the first turtle picks its home range and hatches a new turtle, but that new turtle doesn't pick a home range. Neither outcome is what I want.

How do I set this up to run as intended, so that hatchlings pick home ranges too? Here is one simplified version of my code:

```
to setup-turtles
     crt 1  
     [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
end

to go
     ask turtles [pick-homerange]
     tick
end

to pick-homerange
     while [food-mine < food-required]  ;; if not enough food, keep picking patches for home range
     [;; code to pick home range until it has enough food; this is working okay
     ]
     [;; when enough food, stop picking home range 
      hatch 1 fd 20 ;; now hatch 1, move new turtle slightly away
     ]
end
```

So it is at this last part, once the home range is built, that I want a new turtle to hatch from its parent. I then want that turtle to repeat the pick-homerange procedure. How could that be coded to happen? I've tried writing this every way I can think of; nothing is working. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have each patch equal one "food value", and have turtles grow their home range until their home range supplies them with enough food. I would set this up so that patches "know" to which turtle they belong, and so that turtles know how much food they need, which patches are part of their home range, and the food supplied by their homerange. Example patch and turtle variables would then be:

```
patches-own [
  owned_by
]

turtles-own [
  food_required
  my_homerange
  homerange_food
]
```

Then, your turtles can add patches into their home range until they hit their "food_required", whatever you set that as. For simplicity, in this example I assume that turtles are territorial and so won't "share" home ranges. Further explanation of steps is commented in the code below. This is intended just to get you started- for example, it will hang if you run `pick-homerange` too many times.

```
to setup-turtles
  crt 1 [
        set size 1.5
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
        set food_required 5 + random 5
        set homerange_food 0
        set my_homerange []
      ]
  end

to pick-homerange

  ask turtles [
    ;; Check if the current patch is owned by anyone other than myself
    if ( [owned_by] of patch-here != self ) and ( [owned_by] of patch-here != nobody ) [
      ;; if it is owned by someone else, move to a new patch that is not owned
      let target one-of patches in-radius 10 with [ owned_by = nobody ]
      if target != nobody [
        move-to target
      ]
    ]

    ;; Now add the current patch into my homerange
    ask patch-here [
      set owned_by myself
    ]
    set my_homerange patches with [ owned_by = myself ]

    ;; calculate the number of patches currently in my homerange
    set homerange_food count patches with [owned_by = myself]

    ;; Now grow the homerange until there are enough patches in the homerange 
    ;; to fulfill the "food_required" variable
    while [ homerange_food < food_required ] [
      let expander one-of my_homerange with [ any? neighbors with [ owned_by = nobody ] ]
      if expander != nobody [
        ask expander [
          let expand_to one-of neighbors4 with [ owned_by = nobody ] 
          if expand_to != nobody[
            ask expand_to [
              set owned_by [owned_by] of myself
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      ;; Reassess homerange food worth
      set my_homerange patches with [ owned_by = myself ]
      set homerange_food count patches with [owned_by = myself]
    ]

    ask my_homerange [ 
      set pcolor [color] of myself - 2
    ]

    ;; Now that my homerange has been defined, I will hatch a new turtle
    hatch 1 [
      set color ([color] of myself + random 4 - 2)
    ]     
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed help, I really appreciate it! I'm still struggling with steps 3-4. The initial turtle pick its home range just fine. But once it hatches a new turtle, this turtle doesn't pick a home range. Instead, it just stops at the initial patch it settles on. Or, it immediately hatches new turtles too, without any new turtle picking a home range. But I want each subsequent turtle to repeat "pick-homerange" for itself, then hatch 1, and they fail to do so. How would I get each new turtle to pick a home range, as its parent did? What could I be missing? Thanks!

Comment: I realized a possible reason for the problems I'm seeing. The hatchling inherits all variables from its parent, right? So it thinks it has a home range because it takes its parents values for all variables, e.g., my_homerange, homerange_food, etc. Could this be the problem? If so, how can I tell the turtle to clear that memory so that it can select its own, new home range? I tried resetting each variable to "nobody" after the "hatch 1" command. But I now get an error "The < operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on NOBODY and a number."

Comment: Yes, the hatchling inherits the values from the parent. But since "my_homerange" is dependent on the `who` variable, as soon as you run the `pick-homerange` procedure again, your just-hatched turtles will leave their parents home range. That is why if you just keep running `pick-homerange`, you have the new turtles move to a new patch to set up their own home range. Confirm this by watching which turtles go where. If you'd like, you can cut my code into separate procedures so you have more control over when each block runs- eg. have hatching happen, then have the hatchlings pick a home range

Comment: Hi Luck, thank you again. In order to understand this I decided to return to step 1 & 2, using your code to have Turtle 0 pick its home range. But I'm having trouble. The turtle doesn't pick patches--it just stops on its initial patch. I'm trying to understand why. I assume I'm overlooking something obvious (new to this, sorry!) but could it be within the while loop? I've used "let" to create local variables, but not "ask" to have those variables do something. As written, is this telling the turtle to do those actions, i.e., go to the identified expand_to patch? Sorry and thanks!

Comment: No, the turtle does not move UNLESS it is on a patch "owned" by another turtle. You could definitely pick home ranges by having the turtle move around, but I went with a way that just has the range expand out randomly from the initial patch that the turtle starts on. Check out [this imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/DJ7hj) to make sure you're seeing what I'm seeing.